# Elastic search, query based on another query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6

I want to perform a query and then use the results to perform another query
to ne clear:
I want to perform a query and select the ids and then use those ids to find some users somethink like
`SELECT * FROM`posts`WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,...))` in sql

Comment: why don´t you filter (your subselect fo users) and search for the posts, all in one shot?

Comment: @ibexit can you give me an example or a reference please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results using query string query DSL

In the following example, I have filtered the result based on result_type value

And then grouped the values

example

```
GET .ml-anomalies-.write-high_request_time/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "result_type: model_plot OR result_type:bucket"
   }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "result_type",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can try the same command in the following demo box
https://demo.elastic.co/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?_g=()

Comment: that may work but the problem is that they are in a separate indexes

Comment: you can't do that I guess, you haven't mentioned about different indexes in the question